# Targets, Xcode and interface files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, target

I have two apps which share a lot of source, so I want to put them into one Xcode project and use Targets to build them seperately. Some of the source files have the same name in both projects (for example, `MapViewController.h` and `MapViewController.m`). I thought as an intermediate step, I'd just put the whole classes folder into the merged project (with a different folder name) and use Targets to specify which classes folder to use, then later I'd properly merge what I could into common source files.

The problem I found is that I can't include `.h` files in a Target (the option is greyed out). Do I need to use the same interface file for both Targets and have two versions of the implementation files. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to have two apps with similar naming conventions, with shared code... I'd recommend using the following approach.

Create 3 Xcode projects.

- Project 1: Core Code (shared code,
  resources)
- Project 2: App 1 (import Project 1
  and create a dependency on it)
- Project 3: App 2 (import Project 1
  and create a dependency on it)

Now, every time you change Project 1, both your other projects will be affected.

I've created a project the way you want to right now... And in the long run i've greatly regretted it.

Comment: Why have you regretted the all-in-one-project approach?

Comment: Couple of reasons. 1) The single project becomes too large and cumbersome... A standard Xcode project template is really designed for one project. There is no standard way to create several "Resource" folders for example. 2) Creating multiple projects that have similar scopes creates an annoyance with file naming conventions. You cannot create two different classes with the same name for separate projects. 3) You cannot run Project 2 & 3 at the same time... In the end, it just wasn't worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brad. I've decided to go along with several targets in one project. I want to understand what makes it difficult to do myself. Probably I'll come back to your answer and implement it this way after I understand more.

Comment: One more issue that I ran into recently. I have a project that contains 3 targets. Target 1 = shared code built for iPhone, Target 2 = shared code built for OS X, Target 3 = os x application that imports Target 2. Since i've updated Xcode, I cannot built Target 2 & 3. The "Active Executable" is set to iPhone, even though their OS X targets. I don't know why it thinks their iPhone targets. Haven't found a fix yet. I may have to separate the targets into their own projects.